# How to use the original map key when using the Mapped Types with the Template Literal Types?

Tags: typescript

I need a types like this:

```js
type A<Map extends object, Keys extends Extract<keyof Map, string>> = {
    [NewKey in `prefix-${Keys}`]: Map[Keys/*!!!problem here!!!*/]
}
```

I don't know how to deal with the code where the comment is located.
`Keys` does not split union types with `NewKey`, it is always be `keyof Map`!

---

This is types A actual work:

```js
type B = A<{ a: 1, b: 2 }, "a" | "b">
/*
type B => {
  "prefix-a": 1 | 2,
  "prefix-b": 1 | 2
}
*/
```

But I want a "type C":

```js
// type C = ...
type D = C<{ a: 1, b: 2 }, "a" | "b">
/*
type D => {
  "prefix-a": 1,
  "prefix-b": 2
}
*/
```

Comment: I feel like your question is missing some critical information, could you please provide [mcve] that demonstrate what is not working exactly ?

Comment: @Nicolas I updated some instructions, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use key remapping like this:

```
type C<Map extends object, Keys extends Extract<keyof Map, string>> = {
    [Key in Keys as `prefix-${Key}`]: Map[Key]
}

type D = C<{ a: 1, b: 2 }, "a" | "b">
//type D = {
//    "prefix-a": 1;
//    "prefix-b": 2;
//}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I came up with the answer myself...

```js
type GetKey<FromKey extends string> = FromKey extends `prefix-${infer Key}` ? Key : never

type A<Map extends object, Keys extends Extract<keyof Map, string>> = {
    [NewKey in `prefix-${Keys}`]: Map[GetKey<NewKey>]
}

type B = A<{ a: 1, b: 2 }, "a" | "b">
/* B => {
  "prefix-a": 1,
  "prefix-b": 2
}
*/
```